# Page specific CSS or a single css file when developing a mobile (webkit) based site?

Tags: css, webkit, mobile-safari

I am working on a mobile site for webkit browsers.  I have been trying to find information on using multiple style sheets versus a single css file.  There is a lot of information on this topic, but it not a lot of information pertaining to mobile browsers.  My site will have a bunch of pages that while have page specific css.

For a non-mobile site, it seems like generally people say that a single file will be faster, but that multiple files are easier to develop.  However, on a mobile site is that still the case?

If you put everything in one file, that will get cached after load, but that will make the first load slower.  If you had page specific files, the first page would get loaded quicker, but every other page would then take a hit while making the page specific css http request.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

It sounds like they are saying one file is better as long as its under 1 MB (which my files def will)?

http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/07/12/mobile-browser-cache-limits-revisited/

Answer (score 0):

I would say that use multiple files for development, then when you deploy, minify them to a SINGLE file. I'm assuming that most mobile web browsers will do some kind of caching on your css files. Also I find it hard to imagine a minified mobile site's css file that would grow large enough to worry about really [unless you're doing things like inline/embedded css images]

Comment: Yeah, this is a "reference site" so its supposed to follow best practices even if the css files aren't that big.  It's true though, most of the files should be pretty small.

Comment: Well minified/combined css/js is a web best practice http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html. Don't know if the rules for mobile web are that different.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to take a look at the physical differences when your user agent is a mobile device such as the iPhone.

Typically an iPhone would be operating on a mobile network which would be considerably slower than the average internet connection your average computer would be connected to. This is the only real difference, there may be some subtle difference in the way the different networks operate meaning that separate requests could take longer on a mobile network, but that would be just speculation.

Any processing on the device itself would surely be trival, so in my opinion I recommend what I recommend for websites designed for regular user agents. Develop with multiple style sheets and then use a tool to minify everything into a single compressed file (separate when necessary, conditional IE etc.).

Answer (score 0):

When I build for multiple platforms I use a default style sheet (global.css) for everything, then I write a media specific stylesheet (i.e. screen.css, print.css, handheld.css); from there I create exception stylesheets for specific instances (i.e. screen-ie.css, screen-ie7.css, handheld-iphone.css). This gives me the greatest flexibility for as many presentation methods as possible.

Once everything is exactly how I want it, I minify the "stack" for each instance. So in the case of iPhone: global.css + handheld.css + handheld-iphone.css = iphone.[YYYYMMDD].css to which I call via:

```
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)"
  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/min/iphone.[YYYYMMDD].css"/>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Load only what you need to minimize footprint.

Comment: This site will only be displayed on webkit devices.  Its not a matter of me figuring multiple platforms, just whether its more efficient to break out separate pages into separate files.